# Google App Engine SSL not working with openssl command line tool

Tags: google-app-engine, command-line, openssl, ssl-certificate, google-apps

I installed a SSL certificate for my google app engine app and Google Apps domain. HTTPS is working ok, but when I try to use openssl cli tool I get this error:

```
$ openssl s_client -showcerts -connect mysite.com:443 
CONNECTED(00000003)
140625875744448:error:1409E0E5:SSL **routines:SSL3_WRITE_BYTES:ssl handshake failure:s3_pkt.c:596:**
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 226 bytes
---
```

Any insight on what could be the problem? From what I google'd, it could be a server config problem, but being Google App Engine server, I don't think I can do anything about it.

The main problem is that this prevents connecting securely via low level APIs like openssl, or programming languages (tried with python and it doesn't work). Strange thing is that the web can be accessed using HTTPS with no problems.

If it helps, here's the site: https://www.proofofexistence.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This usually happens when you have set up SNI SSL as this is not supported by default on openssl.

To make this work, just set the -servername flag to the name of the vhost you are testing.

```
$ openssl s_client -showcerts -servername www.proofofexistence.com -connect www.proofofexistence.com:443
```